# Alternate for Chef/Puppet/Jenkins on pushing the instruction set from server to client instead vice versa?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

I like to hear your suggestion for the problem I am facing with infrastructure management.

Problem: Having a server I should be able to create or connect to multiple client system alled nodes to install, run some scripts, generate reports etc.,

To resolve this problem, I found chef/puppet is a good solution but on trying I found that both chef and puppet needs to initiate the process from client side inside the server pushing the instruction from server. Say like in chef when I tried, I need to create a cron job that initiate the chef-client to talk to server to look for any new cookbooks and follow the recipes and execute them. The whole infrastructure fits the problem but except that I want to access the server to say install so and so stuff in this particular node which already established a connection with the server.

Is there a any existing framework to make this happen? I tried both chef and puppet and frustrated on negative results or probably I am missing something on them. Correct me and kindly chip in your suggestions. Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my research I found the best alternative is [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/).
Uses ssh as required.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Capistrano http://www.capistranorb.com/ and see if that fits your needs. No installation required except on your local machine.

You can write tasks in Ruby and then execute them remotely.

Here is an example from their GitHub repo:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v3/README.md#tasks

```
server 'example.com', roles: [:web, :app]
server 'example.org', roles: [:db, :workers]
desc "Report Uptimes"
task :uptime do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    info "Host #{host} (#{host.roles.join(', ')}):\t#{capture(:uptime)}"
  end
end
```

I wouldn't necessarily use Capistrano for infrastructure deployment, but for one-off tasks it is useful.

Comment: @serigo...Thank you so much for your input. This is helpful. Just one question. How does it communicates with the client? Can I install a bin file in client initiating from server? Also I came across a alternative called Ansible. Would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: From the Capistrano GitHub page, `Capistrano is a utility and framework for executing commands in parallel on multiple remote machines, via SSH.` As far installing Capistrano on the remote server, why would you want to? 

You may also want to look into http://rundeck.org/ since it seems more robust for managing infrastructure.

Comment: Just checked out Ansible. It looks like the Python implementation of Chef minus the chef-client. If Evernote, Gawker Media, and edX are using it, it must be good.

Comment: @Serigo..Thanks for your comment. I will look into Capistrano as I checked Ansible working perfectly for my problem. Thanks for your thoughts and helping me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Push-based deployments don't scale very well (to thousands of nodes).

Nevertheless, you can still trigger e.g. `chef-client` runs through an SSH connection (or a message queue with a worker on each node). But be aware that you shouldn't let 1000 nodes converge simultaneously, as it might put excessive load on your Chef server.

Comment: @StephenKing...Thanks for your comment. that is a good idea though but it is more like a hack accessing.Also I am looking fro a framework where no deployment or installation like chef client should be needed in client side. That is why I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is something like [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/), but using ruby: [Orca](https://github.com/andykent/orca). I personally didn't try it, but it should be easier to use than [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/), if you already know ruby (assuming, you do, because you tried puppet and chef). [Orca](https://github.com/andykent/orca) works directly over SSH, all you need is a box that you can connect to. No need for additional installations. And it also positions itself as something in between of [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) (a great tool for deploying applications) and [Chef](http://docs.opscode.com/) / [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/).

Comment: @Draco..Thanks for sharing about Orca with me. Will look into it. I was actually looking for apthon based system as my scripts are in python. So I think Ansible is a best fit.